# how to apply opencv filters to ARGB images in Processing?

Tags: opencv, processing, alpha-transparency, simple-openni

In a part of a project, after displaying `backgroundimage`, I should hide part of it by creating a mask (named `mask1` in my code) and  making first 3000 pixels of `mask1`colorless. Then glare the result by utilizing `blur()` method of OpenCV library. The problem is that it seems that OpenCv library is ignoring opacity(alpha channel) of pixels in `mask1`. As a result, it is impossible to see the `backgroundimage` behind the `blured` image which has been created by OpenCV library. here is my code:

```java
 import gab.opencv.*;
OpenCV opencv;
int[] userMap;
PImage backgroundimage,mask1;

void setup() {
backgroundimage=loadImage("test.jpg");
mask1=createImage(640,480,ARGB);
opencv = new OpenCV(this,640,480);
size(640,480);
}

void draw() {
   image(backgroundimage,0,0);
   mask1.loadPixels();

 for (int index=0; index<640*480; index++) {

        if (index<30000) {
          mask1.pixels[index]=color(0,0,0,0);
        }
        else{
         mask1.pixels[index]=color(255,255,255);
        }
    }
  mask1.updatePixels();
  opencv.loadImage(mask1);
  opencv.blur(8);
  image(opencv.getSnapshot(), 0, 0);
}
```

Is there any other solution to glare `mask1`??[image: I have added 640*480 test.jpg to tun the above code]

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of your entire sketch. We can't run this code. Please narrow this down to just a couple hard-coded images. Voting to close for now, but I'll vote to reopen when you edit the post to include a MCVE.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this, but you'll have better luck if you post the images so we can actually run this program.